# d3.js - updating data in choropleth based on new .csv?

Tags: d3.js

As my username suggests, I am just learning d3.js, using Scott Murray's excellent book. As an exercise, I am attempting to create a choropleth (very similar to the one used in his book) with some public data on dropout rates in the US. I have two separate csvs, one with the data from one group of students, another with a different group's data. I would like the data to update from one csv to another's data on a click. Except for the value names (DRPHI vs DRPBL), names of the csvs, and the values themselves, they are identical. However, the update on click does not work - nothing happens.
Am I missing something very basic here? I apologize if I am. Thank you so much for your time.
My code (based very heavily on Murray's code) is here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>D3: Setting path fills dynamically to generate a choropleth</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../d3/d3.v3.js"></script>
        <style type="text/css">
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <p>Click on this text to update the chart with values for another set of students.</p>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            var w = 500;
            var h = 300;

            var projection = d3.geo.albersUsa()
                                   .translate([w/2, h/2])
                                   .scale([500]);

            var path = d3.geo.path()
                             .projection(projection);

            var color = d3.scale.quantize()
                                .range(["rgb(237,248,233)","rgb(186,228,179)","rgb(116,196,118)","rgb(49,163,84)","rgb(0,109,44)"]);
                                //Colors taken from colorbrewer.js, included in the D3 download

            var svg = d3.select("body")
                        .append("svg")
                        .attr("width", w)
                        .attr("height", h);

            d3.csv("1_dropout_by_state.csv", function(data) {

                color.domain([
                    d3.min(data, function(d) { return d.DRPHI; }), 
                    d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.DRPHI; })
                ]);

                d3.json("us-states.json", function(json) {

                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

                        var dataState = data[i].state;

                        var dataValue = parseFloat(data[i].DRPHI);

                        for (var j = 0; j < json.features.length; j++) {

                            var jsonState = json.features[j].properties.name;

                            if (dataState == jsonState) {

                                json.features[j].properties.value = dataValue;

                                break;

                            }
                        }       
                    }

                    svg.selectAll("path")
                       .data(json.features)
                       .enter()
                       .append("path")
                       .attr("d", path)
                       .style("fill", function(d) {
                            var value = d.properties.value;

                            if (value) {
                                return color(value);
                            } else {
                                return "#ccc";
                            }
                       });

                });

            });

            d3.select("p")
                .on("click", function() {
                    d3.csv("2_dropout_by_state.csv", function(data) {

                color.domain([
                    d3.min(data, function(d) { return d.DRPBL; }), 
                    d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.DRPBL; })
                ]);

                d3.json("us-states.json", function(json) {

                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

                        var dataState = data[i].state;

                        var dataValue = parseFloat(data[i].DRPBL);

                        for (var j = 0; j < json.features.length; j++) {

                            var jsonState = json.features[j].properties.name;

                            if (dataState == jsonState) {

                                json.features[j].properties.value = dataValue;

                                break;

                            }
                        }       
                    }

                    svg.selectAll("path")
                       .data(json.features)
                       .enter()
                       .append("path")
                       .attr("d", path)
                       .style("fill", function(d) {
                            var value = d.properties.value;

                            if (value) {
                                return color(value);
                            } else {
                                return "#ccc";
                            }
                       });

                });

            });
         });


        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You see nothing happening because of the way D3's selections work. [This tutorial](http://mbostock.github.io/d3/tutorial/circle.html) may help understand what's going on.

In brief, you are, in the function that shows the other data, selecting all the existing `path` elements:

```
svg.selectAll("path")
```

and binding data to them:

```
.data(json.features)
```

This data is the exact same as you bound to the elements before. Now D3 computes its join by matching data elements to DOM elements. As you've used the same data before, everything is matched perfectly. Therefore, the `.enter()` selection is empty. As this is the only thing you're operating on, nothing happens.

To do what you want, you don't need to append new elements -- it's enough to bind the new data and update. This is all the code you should need:

```
svg.selectAll("path")
                   .style("fill", function(d) {
                        var value = d.properties.value;

                        if (value) {
                            return color(value);
                        } else {
                            return "#ccc";
                        }
                   });
```

The only thing that needs to be updated is the fill colour, so this is the only thing you need to handle in your code. The path itself (`d` attribute) stays as it was.